# How to query Firebase Realtime database in Android ex. "SELECT column values FROM Table"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I come from an SQL DB background, so i don't know if such query is possible using Firebase realtime DB.

I have the following structure in my Firebase realtime DB. I am trying to find a way to construct a query by which I can get a list of countries where there is a "Service-provider" in.

Using SQL, I would easily write this: SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Address;

I don't want to return all "service-provider" objects as there could be thousands of them! I only want a List of strings containing the countries, and preferably DISTINCT.

**Example:** if there are 3 Service-Providers in USA, 5 in Canada, and 4 in France, then my query would return ["USA","Canada",France"].

```
"Service-Providers" : {
    "PUSH_ID" : {
      "address" : {
        "area" : "ddd",
        "city" : "Berlin",
        "country" : "Germany",
        "lat" : 0,
        "lng" : 0
           },
      "description" : "Shop",
      "firstName" : "fn",
      "lastName" : "ln",
      "phoneNumbers" : [ "123" ],
      "serviceCategory" : "mixed",
      "uid" : "PUSH_ID"
    }
       -
       -
       -
       -
  }
```

Comment: The object beanth `Service-Providers -> PUSH_ID` is a contry object?

Comment: @AlexMamo No, it is the "Service-Provider" object, which contains an Address object, and other String variables and Arrays. The country is a field inside the Address object.

Comment: So you need to list of `Service-Providers` object where a country equals to something? Is this correct?

Comment: No, that would have been easy... I want to know what countries have a "Service-Provider". Example: if there are 3 Service-Providers in USA, 5 in Canada, and 4 in France, then my query would return ["USA","Canada",France"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if there are 3 Service-Providers in USA, 5 in Canada, and 4 in France, then my query would return ["USA","Canada",France"].

There is no way you can achieve this using your actual database structure. So in this case you should create a `Country` object and make a little change in your database structure by adding a new node named `countries`. So your new node should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- countries
         |
         --- pushedId
         |     |
         |     --- name: USA
         |     |
         |     --- providerService: 3
         |
         --- pushedId
         |     |
         |     --- name: Canada
         |     |
         |     --- providerService: 5
         |
         --- pushedId
               |
               --- name: France
               |
               --- providerService: 4
```

Now, everytime you add a new address in your `Service-Providers` node, just increase the number of your `providerService` property by one. That's it!

To get a list of countries, just use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference countriesRef = rootRef.child("countries");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String country = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            countries.add(country);
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your list
        Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
countriesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
[USA, Canada, France]
```